# Can finding patterns between numbers in the rock paper scissors game improve program performance?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, performance-testing

I recently read a book for computer beginners listing a code snip about the rock paper scissors game. The program uses primitive integers 0, 1, and 2 to represent rock, scissors, and paper.

The most straightforward algorithm is to enumerate all the 3x3=9 situations.

```py
a = rand.randint(0, 2)
b = rand.randint(0, 2)

if a == 0 and b == 0:
    print("draw game")
elif a ==0 and b ==1:
    print("winner is A")
...
```

Then, the author hints that if we use little mathematical skills to find the relationship between the three numbers and three possible outcomes, the program can be simplified and run faster.

```py
if a == b:
    print("draw game")
elif a == (b + 1) % 3:
    print("winner is B")
else:
    print("winner is A")
```

Assuming that the probabilities of entering all if-else branches in the two algorithms are not much different (excluding the situation where a player always gestuers stone), then **I think there are no significant performance differences between the two algorithms or even the performance of the latter may be slightly worse,** because the remainder(`%`) operation seems to consume more CPU cycles than `==`.

However, I did a performance test with the following code(`$ time python3 game.py`), which showed that the latter algorithm runs faster. I am curious why this is happening.

I was considering that either `rand.randint(0, 2)` or `print()` is much slower than the comparison operation, so I pre-generated some test cases, put them into the list, and used `pass` instead of `print()`.

```py
def brute_force(a, b):
    if a == 0 and b == 0:
        pass
...


def mod(a, b):
    if a == b:
        pass
    elif a == (b + 1) % 3:
        pass
    else:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testcases = [...]

    num_repetions = 1_000_000
    for i in range(num_repetions):
        for a, b in testcases:
            brute_force(a, b)
            # mod(a, b)
```

`time` with `brute_force` samples(in second): [17.014, 18.069, 16.956, 17.931, 17.919, 17.211, 17.983, 16.984, 17.581, 17.048]
`time` with `mod` samples: [15.921,14.817,15.723,15.715,15.715,16.917,14.957,15.196,16.115,14.763]

Comment: On average `brute_force` will require evaluating half of the 27 `if/elif` comparisons to find the correct block.  So even if one `==` is faster than `%`, a dozen pairs of additional `==` operations probably isn't.  Also you should look at the python `timeit` module.  It will give you better results than using the command line `time` command.

Comment: When having 9 different situations you will need to compare 8 times as a max. with the if else. The average is 4 so I would guess 4 times comparing is slower than (2 times and 1/2 times a mod) ?

Comment: Even simpler/faster: `print(("draw game", "winner is B", "winner is A")[a - b])`

Comment: @Malcolm Not 27 but 9, as already stated in the question.

Comment: @KellyBundy, sorry you are right.  I should know better than to post that late at night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two factors involved in the difference, the number of tests and the intrinsic operation performed during the test.

Let's compute the number of tests for each pair of a/b, as well as the timing for 10M repetitions of each case.

There is only one case in which the number of tests is greater for "mod" than "brute", in all other cases there is a greater or equal number of tests. Even when only 1 test is performed, then the mod approach is ~9% faster than the brute force one. When repeating many times these operations, we can expect on average a ~20% faster code for the mod approach.

```
# brute_tests, mod_tests: number of if/elif evaluated
# brute, mod: average timing over 10M repetitions
# ratio: ((mod/brute)-1)*100

     brute_tests  mod_tests     brute       mod ratio
a b                                                  
0 0            1          1  0.716118  0.650637   -9%
  1            2          3  0.851238  0.931243   +9%  # only mod>brute timing
  2            3          2  0.979143  0.879900  -10%
1 0            4          2  0.957501  0.861337  -10%
  1            5          1  1.022147  0.619716  -39%
  2            6          3  1.121240  0.847757  -24%
2 0            7          3  1.083824  0.869857  -20%
  1            8          2  1.220271  0.854881  -30%
  2            9          1  1.384442  0.738560  -47%
```

Comment: What 3 tests in mod_tests are you talking about? It only has 2 tests.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm talking about the fact that it goes trough if (1), elif (2) or else (3). It's not a test in the sense `==` more a "step" in the branching. And in case of `else` it's special since elif/else are the same level of branching. I guess you could replace `3` by `2` in the specific case of `mod_tests` but I found it easier this way.

Comment: One could also add the number of actual tests (in the sense of `==`), I'll add this when I have a moment.

Comment: Btw [this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3uzLTFBIVbG0VkqwUChKLi7lgfAMrLgUFICcJxDGESioopOYUp0I5qTkwtYbIao2wqwUykRQZYFEEcRHUYTAHAgA) might be faster than both, averaging 2.78 `==` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Kelly yes I'd also expect well crafted branched conditionals to be the most efficient since you're testing each state only once.

Answer (score 0):

**Micro-optimizations will achieve micro-improvements.** Hence, substituting the more readable code of the brute force implementation with the modulo math implementation will certainly be faster, but no one will ever notice this sub-millisecond improvement. Not unless you need to scale your Rock/Paper/Scissors simulation to run trillions of games per hour will it make a difference. And if you are at that scale, you've got other things to optimize first.

Hence, always measure your performance with appropriate code analysis tools first before applying an optimization. Because optimizations generally result in less readable and less maintainable code. So why make your code less maintainable for the next guy if you don't have to?

Now to answer your question. Profiling both the "brute force" and "modulo math" version of the solution can be seen here:

https://python.godbolt.org/z/57dh9z71j

You can clearly see that the brute force implementation has to generate a whole lot more byte code to do those 6 or 7 comparisons.  Whereas the modulo math version doesn't need that much. Hence, we can surmise the latter is faster. And then we could formally conclude it with proper benchmarking.